# Validation not working as expected for opportunity stage traversal

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I have the following validation logic: `IF(AND(TEXT(StageName) = 'Agreement', NOT(PRIORVALUE(StageName) = 'Qualification')), true, false)`, the Idea is if your current stage is `Agreement` and you prior stage is from anything other than `Qualification`, it should throw an error. But it throws the error even if my current stage is `Agreement` and my prior stage is `Qualification`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if this works:

```
AND(
ISCHANGED(StageName),
ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Agreement"),
NOT( ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE( StageName ) ,"Qualification"))
)
```

Comment: An explanation would make this a much better answer. How is this different from what OP already has? Why does that difference matter? Why do you think this should work? You should [edit] your answer to add that.

Answer (score 0):

AND(TEXT(StageName) == 'Agreement', PRIORVALUE( TEXT(StageName)) != 'Qualification')

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you ad some explanation as to what was wrong and why this solves it?